# How to set Values to FormArray in Angular 4 after it has been Initialized?

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have a formArray and I would like to set values to the  array after I get the data at a later point in time but since I have the formArray initialized is it possible it set initial values to the formArray and how do I set the value if I have to

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.businessForm = fb.group({
                    businessInfo: this.buildBusinessArray()
                });
        buildBusinessArray() {
                this.businessInfo = this.fb.array([this.buildBusinessGroup()]);
                return this.businessInfo;
            }

            buildBusinessGroup() {
                return this.fb.group({
                    taxNumber: '',
                    legalName: '',
                    `enter code here`dbaName: '',
                    location: '',
                });
            }
    }
```

This is how I am trying to set the values in the function. But it doesn't set the value it just throws an error

```
this.selected.forEach((selected) => {
    this.businessForm.setValue ({
     'taxNumber': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.taxNumber,
    ' legalName': 
     this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.legalName,
     'dbaName': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.dbaName,
     'location': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.location
    });
});
```

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to use `setvalue` method. you need to set all members.
If you use your code then replace `setValue` with `patchValue` method.

your current code. I have updated method.

```
this.selected.forEach((selected) => {
    this.businessForm.patchValue ({
     'taxNumber': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.taxNumber,
    ' legalName': 
     this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.legalName,
     'dbaName': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.dbaName,
     'location': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.location
    });
});
```

You can also use `setvalue` but you need to initialise `businessInfo` property.

```
    this.selected.forEach((selected) => {
        this.businessForm.patchValue ({
businessInfo: '',//assign your value here
         'taxNumber': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.taxNumber,
        ' legalName': 
         this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.legalName,
         'dbaName': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.dbaName,
         'location': this.merchantInfo[selected.merchantNumber].businessInfo.location
        });
    });
```

Comment: The businesForm has a memebercalled businessInfo which is a formArray .I am not sure how to initialize that with setValues

Comment: Then you just change the method. user patchValue both are similar the difference is, setvalue need all arguments but patchvalue need those which you passed

Comment: I tried patch value it does not update the value. BussinessForm is the formGroupName and the formArrayName is businessInfo, so in that case should the patch value be applied to formGroupName or the formArrayName.

Comment: if patch value is not working than setvalue will also not useful. what issue you face when you use patchValue

Comment: It doesnt show any error, but it just doesnt update the value either.

Comment: Its mean there is an error to you value coming from. Please debug it . if values are coming or not

Comment: I can see the data coming through.